# How to reset an image element's width?

Tags: javascript

When I load an image dynamically, it has the correct dimensions.  However, when I scale the image I manually set the width and height values of the image.

When I load another image, the values are retained from the previous image and it is deformed.  I need to make the element think has no width/height values so it will take the dimensions of the src I set it to.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Clear whatever setting you set to scale it. `img.width = ""` or `img.style.width = auto;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @CrazyTrain the first one you give doesn't work in my tests.

Comment: @dystroy: You're right. The `-1` value works.

Comment: The second solution you gave also works (and mine in answer too).

Comment: Some demos... http://jsfiddle.net/XDM8G/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute) to remove the values you've set :

```
img.removeAttribute('width');
img.removeAttribute('height');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/OSIg/2/edit)

Comment: +1 if the `width/height` attributes are used, this may be safer than setting a value.